# jquery ui autocomplete styles issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to customize my autocomplete input. As for now, it works perfect, but I want to change some styles:

1. the helper, that is placed to the right, I want to move more to the right, because in default it lies on my input. I've found out(via fie that it has class `ui-helper-hidden-accessible` but making changes to jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css made no use.
2. I want to place all items of autocomplete not under the input box, but under the helper span, so the hints from autocomplete won't close my buttons.

Comment: What helper? Do you have any link to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: helper - I meant the message "X results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.". Sorry, I don't have such link

Comment: Did you find a solution? I´m struggling with the same thing and want the same solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the autocomplete list under any div,span etc

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ appendTo: "#someElem" });
```

where #someElem is your helper span id

Rather than using the ui-helper-hidden-accessible , try altering the .ui-autocomplete css to move it around,